# h:outputLink param value disappears after filter on datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am using a primefaces datatable with a column that contains an `<h:outputLink>` with parameter. Everything works great until i filter the datatable. After filter the link's parameter disappears. Here is my column

```
<p:column id="lastNameColumn" filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{user.lastName}"
                    filterBy="#{user.lastName}">
                    <h:outputLink value="/page/userData.html">
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.lastName}"/>   
                        <f:param name="userId" value="#{user.id}" />
                    </h:outputLink>
                </p:column>
```

This generates a link

```
<a href="/page/userData.html?userId=1234">John</a>
```

But after filter the link looks like this

```
<a href="/page/userData.html?userId=">John</a>
```

Does anybody have any idea on what i am missing? Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

How about constructing the *URL* by yourself like this:

```
<h:outputLink value="/page/userData.html?userId=#{user.id}">
    <h:outputText value="#{user.lastName}"/>   
</h:outputLink>
```

Comment: Technically, this won't make any difference.

Comment: @BalusC, I know , still I thought maybe cause of some primefaces bug the `<f:param` is getting lost somehow... I know there are several bugs related to the primefaces datatable filter

Comment: So, what is the recommended pattern/approach to achieve this behavior?

Comment: IMO when it comes to third party libraries and their anomalies , the approach that works for you...